# Google Map API marker not appearing on map on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I am using Google Map Javascript API with marker clustering and InfoBox on a Laravel Website

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

The native red marker shows properly on desktop but doesnt appear on mobile.
However if i click at the location where it should be, my infobox does appear and everything else if ok.

Is there a special setting to be taken into account (as maybe the png used for this marker on mobile display or else?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
    var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
 
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map,icon: image});
}
    </script>
    <!--Load the API from the specified URL
    * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
    * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
    * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
    -->
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking, it was not related to Google Map but to my server .env environment file (I am using Laravel)

APP_URL variable was refering to 'localhost' in .env file  and this APP_URL variable was used in Javascript code (using PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer) for retrieving some server img ressources:
This caused on desktop the ressources to be  properly loaded on google map api but not on mobile.

Replacing localhost by my website url in .env file solved the issue.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue in my setup, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This is the risk with needing a full url for the map icons. I guess it appears in desktop because Google caches the localhost version and reuses it when you deploy to live.